# Preparing the menora

Tags: chanuka, menora-chanukia

Is there an order in which one must prepare the oil/candles each night of Chanuka?

Last night as I was preparing the menorah one of my guests commented that while we light the newest candle first that when we prepare the menorah you should start with the oldest one first - and move forward saving the newest candle for last.  I have never heard of this.  Is this a requirement and if so can you provide a source?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/holidays/chanukah/article_cdo/aid/105045/jewish/How-to-Light.htm

Comment: I don't think there is any specific halacha regarding how you must prepare the candles. You or your guest might have confused how the candles are arranged in general vs. the lighting. I.e., when facing an empty menorah, the 1st night's candle starts on the right. The 2nd night's candle is left of that, 3rd left of the 2nd and so on. In other words, each night a new candle is added left of the others. You light the newest one first and proceed from left to right.

Comment: @DanF agreed on the order of lighting.  The comment was specific as to the order of preparing the candles (and I had never heard of such a requirement)

Comment: Please re-read my comment. In short, I don't think there is any requirement for the preparation, itself. You can place them in the menorah in any order you wish. The description is just what it looks like when you have completed the placement.

Comment: @danf some light right to left when outside

Comment: @DoubleAA That would depend on which side of the menorah you are facing. That is, on the inside, the candles are facing the window and you are behind the menorah, so the newest candle is to your left. On the outside, you are in front of the menorah so the newest candle is to your right.

Comment: @sabbahillel No I don't think it has anything to do with that. The idea is the one closest to the door is Ikar and goes first.

Comment: @DanF, while many adhere to the Jekkisch minhag in this regard (oldest-newest is right-left) the Terumat haDeshen brings the opposite order as Minhog Österreich (Otzar haGedolim, 90) which is followed by some folks I know of Galitzianer yichus.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Interesting item. Can you link a source? Maybe this would form an answer?

Comment: @DanF, I don't think so, it merely challenges the supposition that lighting from left to right w/ new days on the left is a minhag Yisrael. The source is here (I misrecalled the page) http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22627&pgnum=105

Comment: @DanF, see also <http://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/71-austrian-minhogim-a-german-minhogim>